# Django instanced object afected by update

Tags: django, object, orm, instance

```
def get_notifications(request):
    comments_send = EventUser.objects.filter(receive_id=request.user).order_by('-date')[:5]
    comments = EventUser.objects.filter(receive_id=request.user,read=False).order_by('-date')
    comments.update(read=True)
    return render(request, 'home/notifications.html', locals())
```

After creating an instance of EventUser, I am updating the object. After that I render the instanced object but it shows updated.

```
{% for c in comments_send %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Why does this happen? How can I avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean affected by the update?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the query is not executed until it is needed ([django queryset is lazy by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)) and by that time it has already been updated.

So you need to force the "comments_send" to be evaluated. You can force it to evaluate before by casting it to a list.

`comments_send = list(comments_send)`

before the

`comments.update(read=True)`

[You can see when QuerySets are evaluated in the Django Documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

So, although it appears that you are pulling out the `comments_send` before updated all comments with `comments.update(read=True)`, the actual query being sent to the database may differ.

You can force evaluation of the queryset by converting it to a list:

```
comments_send = list(EventUser.objects.filter(receive_id=request.user).order_by('-date')[:5])
```